# VBA Copy column and paste formulas only - not values - to next column

Tags: vba, excel

VBA Copy column and paste formulas only - not values - to next column

Spreadsheet column B has a random mix of values and formulas.  I want to use VBA to copy that column into the next column and only copy the formulas (not the values) into column C.  I was able to use the following VBA to some success but it copies every column past B to infinity (where I want it to stop copying after the first column).

```
Sub Copy_Column_Formulas_NOvalues()
'
' Copy_Column_Formulas_NOvalues Macro
'
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Set oSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
With oSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cel In rng
        If Left(cel.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
            Range(cel.Offset(, 1), cel.Offset(, 1).End(xlToRight)).FormulaR1C1 = cel.FormulaR1C1
            End If
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: remove `.End(xlToRight)`. Actually change `Range(cel.Offset(, 1), cel.Offset(, 1).End(xlToRight))` to `cel.Offset(,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple macro and let me know if it works,

```
Sub Copy_Column_Formulas_NOvalues()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If Cells(i, 2).HasFormula Then
   Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 2).Formula
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Change the `Sheet3` name as per your needs.

Comment: I changed the "Sheet3" to my sheet name.  I changed "B" to the column I wanted to copy "W" (copied to "X") and ran it.  It took awhile but did not copy as desired.  It looks like it still copied B into C.

Comment: The `IF` condition still checks the column B value only. it should search in column W and paste it in X. Alter your formula accordingly

Comment: I changed the "Sheet3" to my sheet name.  I changed "B" to the column I wanted to copy "W" (copied to "X") and ran it.  It took awhile but did not copy as desired.  It looks like it still copied B into C.  So I changed the "2" into the column number "23" (which is Column W) and the "3" to "24" (which is Column X) and IT WORKED.... Takes a little while but does what I needed!!!

Comment: @ssttuuky Thats great !!

Comment: Can you use letters instead of numbers in the if statement?

Comment: @ssttuuky Yes, instead of `Cells(i, 2)` you can use `Cells(i, "W")`